# During testing with Jest Could not find "client" in the context of "withApollo(MyComponent)". Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jestjs

I have a ReactComponent component like this

```
export class ParentComponent {
   render(){
      <ChildComponent {...props} />
   }
}

export default withApollo(ParentComponent)
```

In Child Component

```
class ChildComponent {
   render(){
      <ChildComponent {...props} />
   }
}

export default withApollo(ChildComponent)
```

As you can see both the component is using withApollo.
When I run this set up  in the browser, I am not getting any errors.

TestCase:

```
const parentComponent = mount(
  <ParentComponent
  />
);
expect(parentComponent).toHaveLength(1);
```

But when I test the ParentComponent in Jest, I am getting :

Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of "withApollo(ChildComponent)". Wrap the root component in an ApolloProvider tag.

In the same way if I render the ChildComponent only after loading, the parentcomponent the test case is passing

```
export class ParentComponent {
   render(){
      {!this.props.data.loading && <ChildComponent {...props} />
   }
}

export default withApollo(ParentComponent)
```